# Find a piecewise constant function with certain constraints

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $t\in[0,\infty), x\in[0,1]$. Suppose that $f, h, g\in\mathcal{C}^1\left([0,\infty);W^{1,2}([0,1])\right)$ and for all $t$, $h(t,\cdot)$ and $g(t,\cdot)$ are strictly positive. Can we find a function, $\xi(t,x)$, satisfying $\xi(t,\cdot)\geq0$ for all $t$ and
$$\int_0^1\left(\frac{d}{dt}\xi(t,x)\right)f^2(t,x)dx=0, \quad\quad\quad(1)$$
such that
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{h(t,x)}{g^2(t,x)}\frac{d}{dt}\left(f(t,x)\right)f(t,x)dx\geq \int_0^1\xi(t,x)\frac{d}{dt}\left(f(t,x)\right)f(t,x)dx. \quad \quad(2)$$

**Motivation**. I have a positive function $\phi(t)$ depends on $f,h$, and $g$. I want to prove that $\phi(t)$ is decreasing. After some calculations, I have
$$\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t)\leq -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{h(t,x)}{g^2(t,x)}\frac{d}{dt}\left(f(t,x)\right)f(t,x)dx.$$ If such $\xi$ exists, I can have
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\phi(t)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\xi^2(t,x)f^2(t,x)dx\right)\leq 0.$$
Then, I have $\phi(t)$ decreasing.

**My attempt.** Suppose there exists a constant $C$ such that $g(t,x)>C$. Define $$\xi(t,x)=\begin{cases}0\ &\text{if} \ \left(\frac{d}{dt}f(t,x)\right)f(t,x)\geq 0,\\ \frac{\|h(t,\cdot)\|_{L^\infty([0,1))}}{C}\ &\text{if} \ \left(\frac{d}{dt}f(t,x)\right)f(t,x) < 0. \end{cases}$$ Then, we have a picewise constant function satisfying (2). However, it doesn't satisfy (1).

So, how to find such $\xi$ or how to solve my original problem?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source and motivation of the question, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.